# Flutter lottie animation takes time when it loads for the first time

Tags: flutter

Lottie animation takes 3-4 seconds time to load for the first time.
After first loading it works fine. The size of the lottie json file is 2mb

code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:prm/constants/size_config.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Lottie.asset(
            "assets/animation/flightLoader.json",
            frameRate: FrameRate.max,
            height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical! * 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well 2mb is a lot for a lottie file imo, that's why it take some time to load. You can refer here https://lottiefiles.com/blog/working-with-lottie/optimize-lottie-files-for-faster-page-load-speeds on how to optimise lottie files.